# Ошибка: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

Tags: python, type-error, pyside, qlineedit

Я новичок-программист и у меня возникла проблема. Создавал рандомайзер при помощи модуля PySide. Но как только я пытаюсь вывести на экран случайное число мне выкидывает вышеупомянутую ошибку.
Помогите пожалуйста.

```
v =ui.lineEdit_2.text()
b =ui.lineEdit_3.text()
def bp():
    for i in range(1):
        ui.lineEdit_4.setText(str(random.randint(v, b+1).encode("utf-8").decode("utf-8")))
        return self.randrange(v, b+1)

ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(bp)
```

Ошибка выглядит так: TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

Comment: Такая ошибка возникает, когда к строке пытаются прибавить целое число. Например вот тут: `b+1` - вы к тексту из поля ввода пытаетесь прибавить единицу. Нужно `b` в целое число преобразовать, потом уже складывать.

Comment: Спасибо, я понял. Но как его преобразовать? Обычное int(b) не работает.

Comment: "Не работает" - это не текст ошибки. Что конкретно пишет?

Comment: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: Значит у вас текстовое поле пустое. Нужно туда ввести число, потом уже пытаться значения из него получать.

Comment: Я заполнил поле и числом, и строкой, но ошибка повторяется

Comment: Нужно получать текст из кнопок после нажатия (в обработчике нажатия), а вы получаете сильно заранее (скорее всего сразу после создания текстовых полей)

Comment: Я получаю текст как раз после нажатия кнопки. По коду ошибки проблема кроется в 23 строке. Вот полный код ошибки:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 23, in bp
    ui.lineEdit_4.setText(str(random.randint(v, int(b)+1).encode("utf-8").decode("utf-8")))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: Если у вас код такой же как в вопросе, то вы получаете текст не в момент нажатия. Строки `v =ui.lineEdit_2.text()` и `b =ui.lineEdit_3.text()` нужно перенести внутрь функции `bp`.

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает!